# Improper result returned from ExecuteScriptAsync with WebView2

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, webview

I'm expecting to get an HTMLCollection in the shape of a JSON string returned from this piece of C# code using WebView2, however I only receive an integer array, any idea why? Please see source code and response below.

```cs
var script = @"document.getElementsByTagName('button');";

var text = await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
```

JSON Response:

```json
{"0":{},"1":{}}
```

Comment: Did you get your question resolved? I have the same problem am trying to resolve

Comment: In my case I did call an `async` JavaScript function from my C# code and only got `{}` as the return value. It seems that you can only call a non-async function from C#, if you expect a return value from that call.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after getting return *text*:

```
var jsnSrz = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(text);
```

*jsnSrz* data will render detail you need.